# QML при добавлении графика, работа принудительно завершается

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcreator, qml

Всем привет! Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Подключаю библиотеку **import QtChart 2.3**
И когда переношу график в свою рабочее окно, то при запуске программы она принудительно завершается. Что в этой ситуации делать?

В .qml пишу: `import QtChart 2.3`
В .pro пишу: `QT += charts`
В .cpp пишу:
`#include <QtCharts> using namespace QtCharts;`

Сам использую версию 5.14.2. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что делать? Отлаживать. И не писать `using namespace`

Comment: Но я пока просто добавил график. Пустой. Тем более `using namespace` написано у них на сайте, что нужно добавлять. Вот и не понимаю в чем может быть еще проблема.

Comment: Проблему решил, когда посмотрел этот видос
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxCuSvnjWEE